# TFS 2013 Kanban Board: Show Custom Fields

Tags: tfs

Visual Studio Online allows you to change some elements included on work item cards (custom fields, 'remaining work', etc.) on the Kanban board by clicking on the gear icon. I am using TFS 2013, and cannot find a similar settings menu.

Can I get similar customization in TFS 2013? If so, please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Visual Studio 2013 do you mean TFS 2013?  If so that functionality isn't in TFS 2013.  I believe it's in TFS 2015 which is currently available as a release candidate.

Comment: Backlog card customization isn't in the TFS 2015 RC, but I believe it will be in at RTM.

Comment: [blogs.msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2015/04/29/visual-studio-and-team-foundation-server-at-build-2015.aspx)